# Nested loop behave strange

Tags: loops, nested

This is a simple nested loop:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in i:i+1) {
      print(i)
      print(j)
  }  
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
2
3
```

while I expect:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
```

Can anyone tell me why the output is different to what I expected?

Answer (score 0):

That's a nested loop in a language I (nor probably anyone else) has ever seen, so it's a little difficult to pontificate on what such an imaginary language might do :-)

However, programming language loops, in general, tend to be either closed ranges (includes both end values) or half-open ones (includes the first value but not the second one).

I see by your expectation that you think this is a *closed* range since you expect (in `i/j` pairs):

```
1 1
1 2
2 2
2 3
```

And you're almost certainly right if that assumption on range inclusiuon is correct. For a half-open range, I would expect to see only:

```
1 1
2 2
```

It seems to me that the *only* way you would ever get:

```
1 2
2 3
```

would be if the outer `for` was closed and the inner `for` was half-open but inclusive of the *final* value rather than the first. This seems unlikely since there appears to be no syntactical difference between the two loops.

If the inner loop were instead `for (j in i+1:i+2)`, you would see the output you get for a half-open range, closed at the start.

Bottom line, I don't think there's enough information provided to fully solve this problem, which is why I've just offered general guidance.